# Using FirebaseAuth to Skip Login Screen for Logged In Users Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to skip the login page and straight head to the homepage in my application using FirebaseAuth but `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` gives result twice, first `null` and second `FirebaseUser`. And the application always is taking the first result as `THE` result which than gives me the login screen.

My code is below;

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
        future: authService.getCurrentUser(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
          print("snapshot data");
          print(snapshot.hasData);
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data.uid);
            return MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
              ),
              initialRoute: HomePage.id,
              routes: {
                HomePage.id: (context) => HomePage(snapshot.data.uid),
                WelcomePage.id: (context) => WelcomePage(),
                RegistrationPage.id: (context) => RegistrationPage()
              },
            );
          } else {
            return SafeArea(
              child: Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: colorPalette.white,
                body: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 150,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            "lib/assets/images/logo-with-name.png",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                        child: CustomTextBox(
                          size: 8.0,
                          hintText: "E-Mail",
                          borderColor: colorPalette.logoLightBlue,
                          function: onChangeFunction,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                        child: CustomTextBox(
                          size: 8.0,
                          hintText: "Password",
                          borderColor: colorPalette.logoLightBlue,
                          function: onChangeFunctionTwo,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                            child: Material(
                              elevation: 5.0,
                              color: colorPalette.lighterPink,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              child: MaterialButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  signIn();
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  "Log In",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: colorPalette.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: Text("or"),
                          ),
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(
                                    context, RegistrationPage.id);
                              });
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              "Register",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: colorPalette.logoLightBlue,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
```

**AuthService class;**

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged => _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(
        (FirebaseUser user) => user?.uid,
      );

  // Email & password Sign Up
  Future<String> createUser(String email, String password, String companyName,
      String nameAndSurname) async {
    try {
      final currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      // Update the UserName
      var userUpdate = UserUpdateInfo();
      userUpdate.displayName = companyName;

      await currentUser.user.updateProfile(userUpdate);

      await currentUser.user.reload();

      Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
        await Firestore.instance.collection("users").add({
          currentUser.user.uid: {
            "properties": {
              "companyName": companyName,
              "nameAndSurname": nameAndSurname,
              "eMail": email,
              "currentCashBalance": 0,
              "currentTotalBalance": 0,
            },
            "partners": {},
            "revenues": {},
            "payments": {}
          }
        });
      });

      return currentUser.user.uid;
    } catch (err) {
      if (err is PlatformException) {
        if (err.code == "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE") {
          return "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE";
        } else {
          return err.code;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Email & password Sign In
  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    return (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password))
        .user
        .uid;
  }

  // Sign Out
  signOut() {
    return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }

  // Get Current User
  Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return user;
  }
}
```

The result is like this when the app is launched:

```
I/flutter (12529): snapshot data
I/flutter (12529): false
I/flutter (12529): snapshot data
I/flutter (12529): true
I/flutter (12529): *firebase userid*
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I make it right?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this is because the `builder` is getting executed before retrieving the `userid`.

Therefore you need to use [`CircularProgressIndicator()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html), that will show a circular progress until the result of the `future` is retrieved. For example:

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text(snapshot.data.uid);
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
    }

    // By default, show a loading spinner.
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
);
```

Comment: This would only show the `HomePage` if the `snapshot` has data. I also want to show `WelcomePage` if the `snapshot` **doesn't** have any data. In short, I want my code to be sure that `getCurrentUser()` will not return any `id` and then return `WelcomePage`. Right now, `FutureBuilder` first returns `WelcomePage` no matter if the user is logged in or not and then **in theory** shows `HomePage` if user is logged in.

Comment: This will just show the `CircularPogressIndicator` until the `future` is done, you can keep the if else but this will guarantee that the future is done and now it can easier execute the if block or the else block

Comment: @oividiosCaeremos please check https://dartpad.dartlang.org/896fa75be39ef3abab49f77b2a6855f5 to understand what I mean. This is exactly what you want!! First the `CircularPogressIndicator ` if uid returns `false` then it will go to the login, if it returns `true` then it can go to the welcome

Comment: Peter I understand what you mean but my `snapshot` can only return 2 things. There's either a user or not. I tried your solution but it doesn't work because `snapshot` never has `errors` hence never returns `Scaffold` which has the `Login Page`. Thanks for the reply and effort but it doesn't work on my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //function to check if the user is logged in
Future getCurrentUser() async {
        FirebaseUser _user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
        print("User: ${_user?.email ?? "None"}");
        print(_user);
        return _user;
      }
//using future builder to show whichever screen you want to show loading screen is 
//empty screen with circular progress indicator in center i hope this will help you
     home: FutureBuilder(
              future: getCurrentUser(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return LoadingScreen();
                } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return snapshot.data == null ? LoginScreen() : MainScreen();
                }
                return LoginScreen();
              },
            ),
```